# Directory symlink browsing moves me to new location when autochdir is set

Tags: command-line, gvim, netrw

I have a symlinked directory as such:

```
~/nested
```

Which points to this directory:

```
~/whatever/yetanother/andanother/nested
```

When I launch gvim or command line vim (7.4, with the standard, built-in netrw for directory browsing) on my home directory, undesirable resolution of this symlink is performed:

```
gvim ~
# now use netrw to navigate into "nested"
# now use netrw to open a file inside "nested"
# finally, use the :pwd command in the new file to see the problem
```

I'm not sure if this is a netrw issue or an issue in vim proper. It may be an issue with vim proper, because in netrw when I open `~/nested` I see `Netrw Directory Listing /home/myuserid/nested` at the top of the screen, which is as I would like, but once I go into a file, vim shows the current directory as reported by `:pwd` as `/home/myuserid/whatever/yetanother/andanother/nested`.

So the question, is there a setting to "fix" this, so that vim does not try to resolve my symlinks for me? I want the behavior to match my Linux command line, which doesn't do any such, I would say inappropriate, resolving for me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using Vim 7.4.1294/netrw 154. Have you set `autochdir` or used a plugin which does something similar?

Comment: Perhaps! This could be my fault. Let me check that...  So yes, I do have that set, but why does that matter? I want that set because I want vim's current directory to reflect the buffer I am in right now, and if I have two buffers open, I want the current directory to switch as I switch buffers. So with that turned on vim has to perform symlink resolution? Aren't there better ways for vim to get the path it was launched from?

Comment: Here's a test that you might find interesting. In a shell, run `ls ~/nested/..`. Is the output what you expected?

Comment: You are right, the output is not according to my ideal and not according to the way the command line behaves when you navigate into a symlinked directory, in which case you see no sign of a different path. I believe there are ways that vim can get the "correct" path in this situation. I have done it myself when creating bash scripts. If I use `readlink` for example I do *not* get the result I want. I imagine this is what vim is doing and perhaps it needs to do something different...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10456866/2072269

Comment: Damn, I thought I found a hint [here](http://inlehmansterms.net/2014/09/04/sane-vim-working-directories/), where it discusses `netrw_keepdir`, but I tried toggling that one both ways and it didn't help...